# How to access input field in TinyMCE 5 URL dialog

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm porting a TinyMCE 3 installation to version 5. I set up a toolbar button that opens a dialog that contains a custom page and is therefore loaded using the new `windowManager.openUrl` method. I have some footer buttons, too, and, of course, an `onAction( dialogApi, details )` handler that is invoked when a button is clicked. `details.name` contains the name of the button that was clicked so I can react on every click individually.

It seems, when a regular dialog is used, I configure every input field in my `plugin.js` file and retrieve its value through the `getData` method of first param that in passed into my `onAction` handler. This method does not exist in my `dialogApi` for the [URL dialog](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/urldialog/).

My iframe/dialog contains a dropdown and I want to insert the selected value into the editor instance when a dialog footer button is clicked. I understand I can use `postMessage` to send information from the iframe to the plugin but that's not what I want.

How can I access input fields in the dialog, when a button is clicked and my dialog was opened through `openUrl`? How do I access the document in the dialog's iframe? `this` seems to be the JavaScript object I passed into `openUrl`. `document` is the page where the editor is embedded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made a demo that shows two different ways of getting the data from user inputs in an iframe dialog:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/tinymce-dialog-openurl-demo-fpfew

This blog post is also an excellent resource for working with iframe dialogs in TinyMCE:
https://www.martyfriedel.com/blog/tinymce-5-url-dialog-component-and-window-messaging

The first method in my demo uses a button in the HTML of the iframe itself. That button collects user data and uses `postMessage` to send that data back to the TinyMCE editor.

As you can see, the process is a little more complex using the footer buttons as opposed to the "in iframe" button. Essentially, the footer button sends a message to the iframe in the dialog asking the iframe to collect and insert user data into TinyMCE.

When using an iframe, you have to respect the browser security policy, so most times you can't interact with an iframe directly (the exception being if the iframe uses the same domain). Here's some more information about iframe security policy:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67889/why-do-browsers-enforce-the-same-origin-security-policy-on-iframes

This also means that TinyMCE has no way of knowing what's inside the iframe like it does with a TinyMCE dialog, so the data needs to be fetched "manually". With that in mind, if it's a cross origin request (different domain) there's no way to access the iframe content without using `postMessage`.

The `getData` method mentioned works with TinyMCE dialogs because everything in the dialog is a TinyMCE component. TinyMCE components have a custom concept of values/states that `getData` can access to return data.

When you use a URL dialog, the dialog no longer uses TinyMCE components so it isn't able to collect the data for `getData`, hence it the method doesn't exist. That's why you have to manually get the data needed from whatever elements are in the URL dialog, and send them back to TinyMCE using `postMessage`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer and the sample. I saw the github repo before posting https://github.com/martyf/tinymce-5-plugin-playground and had the idea it may work sending postMessage to the dialog and as a response call sendMessage on the editor.